# NASM integer-to-ascii conversion algorithm not working

Tags: ascii, nasm, division

A sub-part of my NASM program is trying to take an integer and convert it into ASCII for printing on the screen, and it's not working. I can't tell why not. Ignore the stuff about halving/doubling-- that's for the other part of the program which I've left out.

Here's my code:

```
segment .data                                   ;data segment
    return          db      0xA                     ;return character

segment .bss                                    ;uninitialized data
    numc            resb    4               ;reserve 4 bytes for the converted number (int)
    numh            resb    5               ;reserve 5 bytes for halved input number
    numha           resb    5               ;reserve 5 bytes for the halved number in     ascii form
    numd            resb    5               ;reserve 5 bytes for doubled input number
    numda           resb    5               ;reserve 5 bytes for the doubled number in ascii form

segment .text                                   ;code segment
    global  _start                          ;global program name

_start:  
    mov     ebx, 1234               ;number to be converted
    mov     [numc], ebx

_inttoascii:                            ;set registers up
    mov     eax, [numc]
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     ecx, 32

_loop2:
    xor     edx, edx                ;clear edx
    mov     ebx, 10                 ;divide eax by ten
    div     ebx
    add     edx, 48                 ;add 48 to the remainder (ascii of 0 is 48)
    mov     [numha+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
    sub     ecx, 8                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration

    cmp     eax, 0                  ;if eax register is exhausted, we're done.
    jg      _loop2


_inttoascii2:                            ;set registers up
    mov     eax, [numc]
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     ecx, 32

_loop3:
    xor     edx, edx                ;clear edx
    mov     ebx, 10                 ;divide eax by ten
    div     ebx
    add     edx, 48                 ;add 48 to the remainder (ascii of 0 is 48)
    mov     [numda+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
    sub     ecx, 8                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration

    cmp     eax, 0                  ;if eax register is exhausted, we're done.
    jg      _loop3

    mov     eax, 4                          ;select kernel call #4 (write number storing half)
    mov     ebx, 1                          ;default output device
    mov     ecx, numha                      ;pointer to numh
    mov     edx, 5                          ;length of numh
    int     0x80                            ;kernel call to write

    mov     eax, 4                          ;select kernel call #4 (new line)
    mov     ebx, 1                          ;default output device
    mov     ecx, return                     ;pointer to return character
    mov     edx, 1                          ;length of return character
    int     0x80

    mov     eax, 4                          ;select kernel call #4 (write number storing double)
    mov     ebx, 1                          ;default output device
    mov     ecx, numda                      ;pointer to numd
    mov     edx, 5                          ;length of numd
    int     0x80                            ;kernel call to write

    mov     eax,4                           ;select kernel call #4 (new line)
    mov     ebx,1                           ;default output device
    mov     ecx, return                     ;pointer to return character
    mov     edx, 1                          ;length of return character
    int     0x80                            ;kernel call to write

exit:   mov     eax, 1                          ;select system call #1
    int     0x80                            ;kernel call to exit
```

The output atm is just blank lines.

Comment: blah, I was moving the memory address by bit instead of by byte:

    mov     ecx, 32
    mov     [numha+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
    sub     ecx, 8                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration

should have been

    mov     ecx, 4
    mov     [numha+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
    sub     ecx, 1                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was moving the memory address by bit instead of by byte:

```
mov     ecx, 32
mov     [numha+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
sub     ecx, 8                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration
```

should have been

```
mov     ecx, 4
mov     [numha+ecx], edx        ;move result to the correct spot in memory
sub     ecx, 1                  ;switch to another byte for next iteration
```